# Flutter chatbots con dialogflow

Tags: android, flutter, emulación, devices, dialogflow

Estoy probando él **[codigo de dialogflow con flutter](https://github.com/VictorRancesCode/flutter_dialogflow)**

Pero me encuentro con el problema que el bot responde en el emulador de Android, pero cuando lo instalo en un dispositivo real no, *¿qué podrá ser?* *¿tema de assets?* debería cargar los recursos de una URL, **alguien que haya tenido el mismo [error que referencio aquí](https://github.com/VictorRancesCode/flutter_dialogflow/issues/27)**.

Esta parte ya la revise y en el emulador funciona... **(también con su respectivo yaml)**

> AuthGoogle authGoogle =
>           await AuthGoogle(fileJson:"assets/json")

Comment: lo más probable es que sea por permisos de Internet en el AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: si definitivamente ese era el problema, gracias!

Comment: ok ya agregué la respuesta para que la pregunta no quede en el aire, puedes marcarla como resuelta

Answer (score -1):

El error es por permisos de Internet, debes agregarlo en el `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Abre el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` y agrega el siguiente permiso después del tag `manifest` y antes del tag `application`:

```xml
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```